# How to record video call using QuickBlox

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using **QuickbloxWebRTC** framework in ios for video calling. But i don't see any option to record this video call. Can anyone help me if i'm missing something.

My Quickblox sdk version is **2.6.5**
I am following this sample for video calling.

**[sample-videochat-webrtc](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc)**

Thanks

Comment: Video Recording is not a function of QuickBlox framework.

Comment: @Hemang can you suggest some other framework which can make video calls and record them?

Answer (score 1):

Please check Quickbox tutorial page. **[Video_chat_recording](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/Video_chat_recording)**

They have mention all the detail regarding record video session with methods.

> ```
> - (void)setup{
>     // Create video Chat
>     QBVideoChat *videoChat = [[QBChat instance] createAndRegisterVideoChatInstance];
>     [videoChat setIsUseCustomVideoChatCaptureSession:YES];
>
>     // Create capture session
>     self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
>     //
>     // ... setup capture session here   
>
>     /*We create a serial queue to handle the processing of our frames*/
>     dispatch_queue_t callbackQueue= dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
>     [videoCaptureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:callbackQueue];
>
>     /*We start the capture*/
>     [self.captureSession startRunning];
> }
> ```

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput  didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    // Do something with samples
    // ...

    // forward video samples to SDK
    [videoChat processVideoChatCaptureVideoSample:sampleBuffer];
}
```

Note :- You can also get help to record **CustomVideoChatCaptureSession for video chat**

[how-to-use-setcustomvideochatcapturesession-for-video-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055298/how-to-use-setcustomvideochatcapturesession-for-video-chat)

Here mention whole code with example regarding VideoChat Saving

[Quickblox video chat saving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635284/4910767)

I hope this information is enough for you.

Comment: Thanks. But i have already checked your given links. Problem is i can't find any class named QBVideoChat in the sdk. Also there is no createAndRegisterVideoChatInstance method in QBChat class interface. Can you tell me if i'm using the wrong sdk or the sdk got updated?

Comment: I think you are importing only Example . Download SDK from http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS . and you can get detail on this link http://quickblox.com/developers/VideoChat

Comment: No. I'm importing both Quickblox sdk and QuickbloxWebRTC framework. See the documentation. https://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/documentation/sdk/. Do you see any QBVideoChat class reference?

Comment: which file you are importing ?

Comment: In https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc quickblox sdk is also imported. Because i am importing the whole master branch. Code is using .pch file to reference the sdk. So i'm not importing anything. Also even if some how i get your example code working. I don't think it will record the audio too. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BadalShah I need your help for integrating Quickblox.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! If that's the case, maybe you can also use the tool I installed. You can visit the official site of AceThinker Screen Grabber Pro to install it. Then, click the "Record" button and hit "Fullscreen" to start recording your video call on QuickBlox. Next, just simply hit the "Stop" button on the floating toolbar to end and save your recorded call automatically.